# NSWindow - click outside to hide window

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nswindow, nsstatusitem

I'm doing first steps in programming for Mac. I had only little experience of iOS development. 
I need to build very simple app, sitting in menu bar.
I wanted it a little custom to decided to use NSWindow and attach it to the NSStatusItem.

My AppDelegate looks so:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    float width = 30.0;
    float height = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] thickness];
    NSRect viewFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height);
    statusItem = [[NSStatusItem alloc] init];
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:30];
    [statusItem setView:[[TSStatusBarItem alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame]];


}

- (void)buttonClicked:(int)posx posy:(int)posy {
    [_window setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevelKey];
    opened = !opened;
    NSLog(@"Window is shown: %i", opened);

    [_window setFrameTopLeftPoint:NSMakePoint(posx, posy)];

    if(opened == YES) {
        _window.isVisible = YES;
    } else {
        _window.isVisible = NO;
    }

}
```

It's code of TSStatusBarItem

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code here.

    if (clicked) {
        [[NSColor selectedMenuItemColor] set];
        NSRectFill(rect);
    }

    NSImageView *subview = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0, 20, 20)];
    [subview setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"]];
    [self addSubview:subview];


}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event
{

    NSRect frame = [[self window]frame];
    NSPoint pt = NSMakePoint(NSMinX(frame), NSMinY(frame));
    NSLog(@"X: %f and Y: %f", pt.x, pt.y);

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    clicked = !clicked;

    [appDelegate buttonClicked:pt.x posy:pt.y];


}
```

Window shows and hides pretty well, but only if I click on StatusItem. I would like to add behavior of hiding window, when user clicks outside or when selects another item in menu bar (just similar working to typical NSMenu application).

How to do it? If you have any idea how to simplify my code (sorry, I'm newbie in Mac coding) - let's say please.

Comment: Why do you add a new image view every time draw rect is called? I recommend adding that part of your code to the ini t method, or drawing the image programmatically. ;)

Comment: Also, do you have an NSMenu appear when the status item is clicked?

Comment: @TannerSilva No. I just 'open' NSWindow and move to the point of NSStatusItem.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking you could make your AppDelegate a NSMenuDelegate, which would notify you when the status menu closed.

Answer (score 4):

Register for `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` or `NSWindowDidResignMainNotification` to get notified in case the window looses focus:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    SEL theSelector = @selector(closeWindow); 
    NSNotificationCenter* theCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
    NSWindow* theWindow = [self window]; 
    [theCenter addObserver:self selector:theSelector name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:theWindow]; 
    [theCenter addObserver:self selector:theSelector name:NSWindowDidResignMainNotification object:theWindow]; 
}
```

Now the following is executed in case the window looses focus:

```
-(void)closeWindow
{
    [[self window] close];
}
```

Alternatively use `NSPanel` which hides automatically in case focus is lost.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Hm... it seems doesn't react for clicking outside. I tried even call NSLog, but in vain. Also tried NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification and NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification. Didn't work too. :(

Comment: It works only if I have Title Bar enabled. The same when Title Bar is enabled WebKit works ok, but if not, it makes strange things. ;/

Comment: It seems that when title bar is disabled, the window never becomes key. To solve this, subclass NSWindow and override the canBecomeKey property to return true. Then override windowDidResignKey in NSWindowDelegate.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version of @Anne's answer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didResignKeyNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { _ in
    self.window?.close()
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSWindow.didResignMainNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { _ in
    self.window?.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self window] close];
}
```

**Try it
   This will work only if your app is in focus.
   And in order to make it focused... Try this too - :**

[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];